# How can I login to Ubuntu 7.04 without being able to see the screen?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-server

I need access to an old VMWare Ubuntu image and I can't see the login screen.  Well, I can see enough to know that it's Ubuntu 7.04, but not the actual area where I type credentials.

This is the same problem as here: [Ubuntu Login Screen Resolution is Off](https://serverfault.com/questions/51628/ubuntu-login-screen-resolution-is-off)

But I can't log in.

**What would the sequence of keystrokes be to login to Ubuntu 7.04?, or is there a way I can force it to console login?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to log in by hitting `Ctrl-Alt-F1` (or possibly `Ctrl-Alt-F2`) and logging in to a text console, assuming VMWare is capturing your keystrokes. After that, you can edit the file mentioned by using `nano` (iirc, 7.04 had nano in it) or `vim`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot: I solved my problem but this may have been the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual machine runs sshd (usually they do), you could just ssh to it. If it gets its address via DHCP you can look up its MAC address in VMware Client and then check leases on your DHCP server.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't normally open ports, otherwise this would have good.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to type either
`login`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`password`<kbd>Return</kbd>
or
`login`<kbd>Return</kbd>`password`<kbd>Return</kbd>.

Good luck!